# Delete label request returning 400 even though label exists

Tags: gmail-api

I am having issues with the label delete Gmail API.
No matter what label I submit, I get the error response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalidArgument",
    "message": "Invalid delete request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid delete request"
 }
}
```

To reproduce, I first make the request:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels
{"labelListVisibility":"labelShow","messageListVisibility":"show","name":"C2"}
```

Which succeeds and then immediately after I send:

```
DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels/C2
```

Which produces the aforementioned error. I can see the label in my gmail inbox so I know it is successfully created and present. Any advice on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

### You cannot delete a label by name, but must do so by its ID

See [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/delete). The Id of the label is contained in the response of the

`POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels`

request:

```
{
 "id": "Label_3",
 "name": "C1",
 "messageListVisibility": "show",
 "labelListVisibility": "labelShow"
}
```

You can also [list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/list?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%7D) all you labels to retrieve their IDs.

The delete request should look something like:

`DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels/Label_3`

whereby `Label_3` should be replaced by your label ID.